# How to render pages based on the selection made in the first page of the wizard

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, jface

I have 4 Wizard pages , say page1 , page2, page3 and page4. Page1 consists of 3 radio buttons. So based on the selection of radio button, one of the 3 pages should be opened.

i.e. if I select the 1st radio button and press Next , then page2 should be opened.
     similarly 2nd radio button- page3
               3rd radio button - page4

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `getNextPage` method of your `Wizard` or `WizardPage` classes.

For `Wizard` the method is:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage(IWizardPage page)
```

You are given the current page and return the next page.

For `WizardPage` the method is:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage()
```

The default behavior of `WizardPage.getNextPage` is the call the `Wizard` get next page:

```
public IWizardPage getNextPage() {
    return wizard.getNextPage(this);
}
```

There are also similar `getPreviousPage` methods.